# What is the weak star topology on $L(X,U')$?

Tags: functional-analysis

The following is taken from Peter D. Lax book Functional Analysis. Exercise 5 page 165.

Let $X,U$ be Banach spaces. I want to define the weak* topology on the set of bounded linear maps from $X$ to the dual of $U$ denoted $\mathcal{L}(X,U')$.

Am i correct in assuming that a sub basis for this topology is given by the sets

$$\{M\in \mathcal{L}(X,U')\mid |(Mx)u-(M_0x)u|<r\}$$

where $x\in X$, $u\in U$, $M_0\in \mathcal{L}(X,U')$ and $r>0$?

---

EDIT: If my understanding of this is correct, we want the map $T:\mathcal{L}(X,U')\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $T(M)=(Mx)u$ to be continuous, for any $x\in X$, $u\in U$. Therefore the inverse image of every open set $(a,b)$ must be open in $\mathcal{L}(X,U')$.

Suppose that $(M_0x)u\in (a,b)$. Choose $r$ such that $B_r[(M_0x)u]\subseteq (a,b)$. This denotes the ball of radius $r$ centred at $(M_0x)u$. Then

$$\{M\in \mathcal{L}(X,U')\mid |(Mx)u-(M_0x)u|<r\}\subseteq T^{-1}\Big((a,b)\Big).$$

On the other hand every set of the above type must be open so this is indeed the smallest topology which makes the above function continuous?

Comment: The weak$^*$  topology is defined on dual spaces. Is ${\cal L}(X,U')$ the dual of some topological vector space?

Comment: Do you mean there is something wrong with my phrasing? This is from my textbook.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is your topology the weakest one that makes the mapping from ${\cal L}(X,U') \to \mathbb R$ given by $$M \mapsto (Mx)(u)$$ continuous for every $x \in X$ and $u \in U$?

Comment: I edited to explain my reasoning

Comment: Perhaps I am misremembering but I thought that was called the weak operator topology.

Comment: You may be right since the weak* topology is never defined in my book. The exercise in the book is given as: define it. Maybe my approach is wrong then.

Comment: Would you mind naming the book and exercise number?

Comment: Yes I should have done that from the beginning. I've updated the question. Its Lax book on functional analysis